# How to access image folder in jni function

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a android project and within that project I have a folder that contain some images.Now what i want is to access that folder within a jni function. So how should I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to use JNI to access the files? Can't you use the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API for this?

Comment: @Angelo van der Sijpt  No.I just want to access them using jni.after building the project the image folder and c++ file(build as a linux shared library) going to be reside in an apk file.What i want is to access the image folder from shared library.The c++ file will read each image in the folder and do some image processing stuff on each image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Android application is essentially a zip file, but there are a lot of nice helpers to get to those resources. First thing you need to remember is that these files are not actually in a *folder*, unless you put them there.

That said, there are a number of possible solutions for you situation.

### JNI (almost) all the way

The most JNI-y way to go about things is to use have a method like

```
private native void processResources(AssetManager assets);
```

in your `Activity`, and use JNI to pry all the necessary resources from it, put them somewhere on disk, and process them.

### Mix in a bit of Java

Probably an easier way is to have some Java code that helps with the resource management; something like

```
private void processAll() {
    for (String resource : getResources().getAssets().list(mydir)) {
        process(getResources().getAssets().open(resource));
    }
    // exception handling omitted for readability
}

private void process(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    for (int read = in.read(buf); read > 0; read = in.read(buf)) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    process(out.toByteArray());
}

private native void process(byte[] resource);
```

and do the native processing based on the `byte[]`.

### Prepare files on the file system

A third solution is to move the files out of your bundle and onto the file system, and then point your native code to that directory.

### So?

In the end, it all depends on what you exactly want to do with your resources, and whether or not they *really* need to be on the file system. I would keep things as close to Java as possible, and only go native when you really have to (e.g., your image manipulation code).